# Selected option in Angular app is not displayed until clicking on dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have select in the template where selected option is not visible until I click select itself. It is seen in the code, and everything OK with styles:
[image]
After click:
[image]
// advanced.component.html

```
<div class="select-div select-div-{{i}}">
  <label for="shortName">
    {{'advanced.data-type' | translate}}
  </label>
  <select #selectField
          id="shortName"
          class="form-select"
          formControlName="shortName"
          (change)="setFieldValues(selectField.value, i)">
    <option selected>{{'drop-down.please-select' | translate}}</option>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of selectedArchiveFields">
      <option *ngIf="currentLang === 'de'" value="{{field.shortname}}">{{field.name}}</option>
      <option *ngIf="currentLang === 'en'" value="{{field.shortname}}">{{field.nameEN}}</option>
    </ng-container>

  </select>
</div>
```

// advanced.component.ts

```
export class AdvancedComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public currentLang: string;
  public conjunctions: Array<string> = ['AND', 'OR'];
  public archiveTypesFields: Map<string, Array<ArchiveMDField>> = new Map();
  public selectedArchiveFields: Array<ArchiveMDField> = [];
  public advancedForm: FormGroup;
  public isMobile: boolean = false;

  private translateSub: Subscription | undefined;
  private storeSub: Subscription | undefined;
  private searchTypesSub: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private advancedService: AdvancedService,
              private translateService: TranslateService,
              private widthStore: Store<{ appWidth: AppWidth}>) {

    this.currentLang = this.translateService.currentLang;
    this.translateSub = this.translateService.onLangChange
      .subscribe((params: LangChangeEvent) => {
        this.currentLang =  params.lang
        this.advancedForm.patchValue({systemLang: params.lang})
      });

    this.advancedForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      archiveType: [null, Validators.required],
      combinations: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          shortName: [null, Validators.required],
          operand: [null, Validators.required],
          primaryInput: [null, Validators.required],
          secondaryInput: null,
          inputType: [null, Validators.required],
          systemGroupId: [null, Validators.required],
          languageDependant: [null, Validators.required],
          multiSelect: [null, Validators.required],
          hierarchical: null
        })
      ]),
      conjunction: ['AND', Validators.required],
      systemLang: [this.translateService.currentLang, Validators.required]
    });

    // SET FORM VALUES ON BACK BUTTON (BAD BAD PRACTICE!)
    // if (localStorage.getItem("advancedForm")) {
    //   const advancedFormJSON = localStorage.getItem("advancedForm");
    //   if (advancedFormJSON) {
    //     this.advancedForm.patchValue(JSON.parse(advancedFormJSON));
    //   }
    // }

    this.storeSub = this.widthStore.select('appWidth')
      .subscribe((data: AppWidth) => {
        this.isMobile = data.isMobile;
      }
    );
  }
```

I can make it get visible forcibly if removing `formControlName="shortName"` from the select. All other things/attempts don't work.